# Remove white spaces when posting a variable in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql

I have this form here:

```
<label for='per_pjese'>Per Pjese:</label>
<select id = "per_pjese" name="per_pjese" >
<option value = "2">Jo</option>
<option value = "1">Po</option>
</select>
```

Now, i get the variable like this:

```
$postPer_pjese = stripslashes($_POST["postPer_pjese"]);
```

My issue is that when it's posted in the database, it's posted with white space... i.e:

```
1' ' where ' '  signifies white space
```

Comment: It's not coming from the code you've posted, show the code that performs the database update.

Comment: Barmar, you're so right... :)
Thanks..i found out what was wrong..please write it down and i'll accept the answer!

Comment: If you found the problem, you should post your own answer.

Comment: Sorry for my english, i meant write that as an answer so i could accept :)

Comment: But it's not an answer, it's a request for you to show us more of your code so we can point out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$postPer_pjese = str_replace(' ', '', stripslashes($_POST["postPer_pjese"]));
```

to remove any spaces in the string.

**EDIT**

This is assuming that the form you have given is not the one using.

Otherwise the problem could be in the insert statement that is not given.

Comment: Where could the spaces have come from? None of the options have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only worried about removing leading or trailing whitespace, take a look at php's [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: Since the option values don't have spaces in them, why is this necessary?

Comment: My comment was more general with regard to removing whitespace. In the example, the posted variable `$_POST["postPer_pjese"]` is not present in the HTML code.

Comment: But he should fix the root cause that's adding the whitespace, not fix the symptom by removing it later. And I suspect the nonexistent variable is just a typo in the question.

Comment: It's hard to say where the value is coming from with the posted information. If it is a hardcoded value in a select list, then it would make sense to fix the HTML code. If it came from submitted user input in a text field, maybe not.

Comment: He posted the HTML, it's a select list with hardcoded values, and there are no spaces.